# Are there terms for the curves with/without inflection points?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology

I'd like to classify some planar curves with/without inflection points.

I need some precise and simple description for the curves with/without inflection points.

I'm presently planning to call the curves "inflected"/"non-inflected".
Are there better alternatives already in the mathematics?

Comment: If the curves are simple and closed, it might be preferable to use _convex_ (no inflection points) and _non-convex_, from the properties of the Jordan region they bound.

Comment: The curves here are simple but open, possibly concave up, concave down or with inflection points. Maybe concave, convex, inflected? But I want a binary description.

Comment: Offhand I don't know standard terms; (_un_-) _flexed_ has fewer syllables, and follows an old convention -- maybe 19th Century algebraic geometry -- of using _flex_ as a noun. <> If informality is all right, maybe U-shaped and S-shaped, which are evocative (if not literally correct).